# How to express `Congruence` property in a general way in Coq/Agda/Idris?

Tags: coq, idris, agda

I'm working on sf/plf chapter `Equiv`, and it mentioned that "[behavioral equivalence is also a *congruence*](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/plf-current/Equiv.html#lab23)", and express this conclusion via several different Theorems, like `CAss_congruence`, `CWhile_congruence`, `CSeq_congruence`, `CIf_congruence`, etc. And each of them corresponding to a constructor of `com` (which is the type name of AST which expressing command in the `Imp` toy language).

And these code seems very verbose, so I'm wondering is there a **simple** way to express the *congruence* property of behavioral equivalence of `com`, just like

```
Theorem cequiv_congruence : ∀ (cp : com_pattern) (a b : com),
    cequiv a b -> cequiv (cp a) (cp b).
```

The `cp : com_pattern` here means a `com` with a single hole not filled, and `(cp a)` means the hole was filled by `a`, but I don't know how to define `com_pattern` here.

And further more, I want to express the *congruence* property in a **general** way, which is not only for `cequiv_congruence` relation of `com`, but for all expression tree, and the equiv relation on them.

Maybe it is something like:

```
Definition congruence := λ (exp : Set) (equiv : exp -> exp -> Prop) ⇒
    ∀ (ep : pattern exp) (a b : exp),
        equiv a b -> equiv (ep a) (ep b).
```

But I also don't know how to define the `pattern` here.

Comment: Have you looked into `setoid_rewrite` and defined `Proper` instances?

Comment: @larsr No, sf/lf is the only thing I have read about Coq,  setoid_rewrite seems like something I'm looking for, and I'll check it out, thanks very much.